# "Data not available" when using Database.rollback() in custom save action

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller, savepoint

In my custom edit page for `LineItem__c` records I have overriden the save button with my own implementation which does not only save the record itself but also change to child records.

```
<apex:page standardController="LineItem__c" extensions="LineItemEditCtrlExt">

    <head><title>{!DeliverableLineItem__c.Name}</title></head>

....

      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
          <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!doSave}" />
      </apex:pageBlockButtons> 

      <apex:pageBlockSection>
          <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.DeliverableLineItem__c.fieldsets.EditBasic}" var="field">
              <apex:inputField value="{!lineItem[field]}"  />
          </apex:repeat>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

To handle errors in an ACID-way I rollback to a `Savepoint` in case an exception is thrown.

```
public with sharing class LineItemEditCtrlExt  {

    public LineItem__c lineItem { get; set; }
    public ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl;


    public LineItemEditCtrlExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl) {
        this.stdCtrl = stdCtrl;
        lineItem = (LineItem__c) stdCtrl.getRecord();
    }


    public PageReference doSave() {
        Savepoint toBeforeState = Database.setSavepoint();

        try {
            upsert lineItem;
            saveChildrenX();
            saveChildrenY();

            return stdCtrl.view();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);

            // No error when I comment out next line!!
            Database.rollback(toBeforeState);

            return null;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

But this always leads to strange

> Data not available

errors when the user tries to save again after he was presented with a error message meaning a user clicks Save, sees an validation error on the page and then immediately clicks Save again.

**This does not happen at all when I remove the Database.rollback() call. Why is that so? And how should I rewrite my custom save to work?**

Comment: It's seems to be related to https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000090EvIAI but as I am using an upsert instead of stdCtrl.save() I miss the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the database upsert results in an ID value being allocated and set on the SObject, that ID value remains in the Apex code even though the ID value has been discarded as part of the rollback process in the database. So the next time you upsert the data for that ID is "not available".

So add this (a clone that does not preserve the ID) right after the rollback:

```
lineItem = lineItem.clone(false, false, false, false);
```

**PS**

Or as discussed in the comment thread, removing the savepoint/rollback might be the best solution. See the [Transaction Control](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm) documentation; savepoint/rollback is provided for special cases.

Comment: you mean lineItem = lineItem.clone(false, false, false, false)?!

Comment: @RobertSösemann Yep. I'll change that.

Comment: I added that line and it didn't change anything :-(

Comment: @RobertSösemann OK, then have a look for that kind of problem in saveChildrenX and saveChildrenY.

Comment: @RobertSösemann My first suggestion would be to lose the savepoint/rollback as the transaction won't commit if there are DML errors. But perhaps you need it for some other reason...

Comment: You mean there is no reason to have them as all DMLs inside my try are auto-rollbacked on error? Is this really the case even if I have multiple DML statements in different methods?! Is this in the documentation? Any why would anyone use rollbacks then?

Comment: @RobertSösemann This [Transaction Control](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm) documentation is one reference. The way I understand the design is that Salesforce have designed their code to work most of the time without any explicit transaction statements being needed. In a large code base I only have a few. One is code that does a complex calculation where you can preview the result before committing it; another is where a sub-set of errors is explicitly handled; another is where an approval process error wasn't getting reported.

Comment: Now I know why I had to use rollbacks... If you catch the dml error to convert them to nice page messages you basically break the built in auto rollback.

Comment: Note that replacing lineItem with a clone means that if a DMLException was thrown on the upsert of the lineItem due to a validation rule, for example, you won't get the field-level error message on the inputField since you've just thrown away the record with the error.